# Full end to end encryption with AWS Elastic Load Balancer, Nginx and SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

You will see a lot of [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611783/ssl-not-working-with-elastic-load-balancer-and-nginx) on the web telling you the way to setup SSL with an AWS ELB is to set up a certificate on the load balancer and then forward traffic from port 443 to 80 so that traffic between the load balancer and nginx is unencrypted. To me this doesn't appear very secure as you have unencrypted data flowing over a network connection. What if that data is credit card information?

My questions:

1. Does having and unencrypted connection between the load balancer and nginx pose a security risk?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, how would I setup nginx to allow the secure connections from the load balancer?
3. Would this involve setting up an ssl certificate on each nginx server?
4. What would the nginx config look like if it needs to be different than a standard ssl setup where nginx is not behind a load balancer?

Comment: Great question about security. Many companies security compliance requires "end to end encryption" ALB -> host over HTTP violates that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does having and unencrypted connection between the load balancer and nginx pose a security risk?

- If talking about credit card data and stuff like this: Yes.

> If the answer to 1 is yes, how would I setup nginx to allow the secure connections from the load balancer?
>   Would this involve setting up an ssl certificate on each nginx server?

- The `nginx` config is / would be fairly standard, nothing fancy.
- Yes, you would need a ssl certificate on each machine running `nginx`. You could use one cert for this, you don't need necessarily multiple. Besides: Using [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) it's now fairly easy and automated possible to get certs, free of charge.
- If you send sensitive data between the ELB and your machines, make sure this / these link(s) is encrypted as well. How to do this is explained [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#configure-https-listener).

> What would the nginx config look like if it needs to be different than a standard ssl setup where nginx is not behind a load balancer?

- There isn't a major difference, as far as I know. If you need the client IP for whatever reason, put these lines into your `nginx` config:

  ```
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  set_real_ip_from ${ip-of-your-elb}/${netmask-of-your-elb};
  ```

- Bonus: Set up your "own ELB", using the great [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) for example. Going this way, you could take care of the encryption between the ELB and the backend machines yourself, using whatever seems / is appropriate: https, ssh tunnels, a VPN, ...

Comment: The trouble with HAProxy is that it doesn't provide a high availability system like ELB does. You would need to setup multiple HAProxy servers and round robin DNS to achieve something similar but even then it wouldn't be as robust a setup

Comment: @JamieD DNS isn't made for high availability, so I wouldn't recommend to use DNS round-robin if you're after HA. You could use a virtual IP, two (or more) instances, and software which does health checks and IP failover. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/733177/how-to-create-a-high-availability-application-server/733195#733195) answer as well. Been there, done (and doing) that. Regarding "[...] but even then it wouldn't be as robust a setup": I strongly doubt this. Many big websites / services (like StackExchange for example) use these kinds of setups, but anyway, ...

Comment: ... this is of course up to you.

Comment: im not saying you cant achieve a HA setup using something like HAProxy, but why (if you're already using AWS) would you goto the trouble of rolling your own system when ELB works very well and is likely to be a much better system than most people are capable of creating themselves?

Comment: @JamieD Well, because as I described in my answer, you're then able to implement all the stuff you would like to. And yeah, you're right, setting up a system like this isn't that easy.