# How to make a reverse proxy server fail-safe and stable?

Tags: reverse-proxy, hardware

I'm planning to put a reverse proxy before our web servers, mainly for high availability, load balancing and SSL tunneling. Probably [nginx](https://nginx.org/) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

I understand that the proxy becomes the SPOF of the architecture so I'm looking for hardware solutions to make it as fail-safe and stable as possible.

What are the best practices in terms of hardware, knowing that the needed specs are pretty minimal in terms of disk space, RAM and CPU?

Any other suggestion for the whole reverse-proxy-being-spof thing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go the "hardware route", have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/733177/how-to-create-a-high-availability-application-server/733195#733195). In this answer I've described how one could / would implement such a setup using software.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was also looking for advices regarding the hardware itself (SSD drives  or not, fanless cooling or not, dual network cards, etc.).